# Python Selenium: Clicking on the next page not working

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using the following code to  click on the next page, by clicking the next element.

However this code is not working. Any thoughts on what I might be doing wrong.

Final goal:

Use BeautifulSoup on each of the pages.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
from urllib.request import urlopen as ureq
import random
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By



chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
prefs = {"profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications": 2}
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)

# A randomizer for the delay
seconds = 1 + (random.random() * 2)
# create a new Chrome session
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
driver.implicitly_wait(30)
# driver.maximize_window()

# navigate to the application home page
driver.get("https://www.fda.gov/inspections-compliance-enforcement-and-criminal-investigations/compliance-actions-and-activities/warning-letters")
time.sleep(seconds)
time.sleep(seconds)

next_page = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "next")
#print (next_page.get_attribute('innerHTML'), type(next_page))
next_page.find_element(By.XPATH("//a[@href='#']")).click
# next_page.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT("Next")).click()
```

This code does not click on the next page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select your element more specific and wait [`.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable())`](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html) - This will give you the next page.

##### Example

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))

url = 'https://www.fda.gov/inspections-compliance-enforcement-and-criminal-investigations/compliance-actions-and-activities/warning-letters'

driver.get(url)

WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#datatable_next a'))).click()
```

Comment: Thanks, this works for me. Little more help, how do I get the content of the next page loaded to the driver?

Comment: I tried the following: ```window_after = driver.window_handles[1]
driver.switch_to.window(window_after)```

Comment: It is automatically there, simply call `BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source)` to create your object.

Comment: Actually, I tried running the webdriver wait in a for loop, its not working for me: ```for i in range(0,3):
    WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#datatable_next a'))).click()```